# How to wrap a process with an activity indicator?

Tags: shell, terminal, progress-information

I have a process which I'm running in a terminal session. The process prints nothing (or perhaps it prints a lot of junk which I redirect somewhere), and takes quite a while, e.g. a couple of minutes.

Now, I want to wrap it somehow, so that while it's running, I'll get some sort of visual indication of it not being stuck. It could be a rotating bar (`-`->`/`->`|`->`\`->`-`), or some point which goes back-and-forth on the line, or at worst even just some printouts with newlines every once in a while.

Bonus points if this progress indicator becomes "stuck" if the process becomes stuck and its CPU usage drops to 0 etc.

Comment: What are the indications that your process becomes "stuck"? How can an external process know that?

Comment: @glennjackman: An external process can't really know this, but it can make a guess by looking at the CPU usage and noticing when it drops to 0. But like I said, that's just icing on the cake.

Comment: you could write a script that just generates the spinner. Launch it in the background before you invoke your long running program: `spinner.sh & your_program`

Comment: @glennjackman: I know I can just "do it myself"; the question is whether there's some ready-made facility for this. I mean, lots of apps/utilities use spinners and progress bars, I was hoping this is available separately somehow.